# How to run pg_rewind in postgresql docker container

Tags: postgresql

Got the same question. Running PostgreSQL replication clusters in docker container with the official postgresql docker image, now is trying to work out an approach to do failover.

When running `pg_rewind` against the previous primary container without stopping PostgreSQL service, the failure occurs:

```
pg_rewind: fatal: target server must be shut down cleanly
```

But if I run:

```
docker exec <container-name> pg_ctl stop -D <datadir>
```

The container is restarted because of the restart policy `unless-stopped`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by myself.

Just stop the existing container and run command in a new container using the same image and volume mounts, something like:

```
docker run -it --rm --name pg_rewind --network=host \
--env="PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata" \
--volume=/var/lib/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw \
--volume=/var/lib/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql:rw \
--volume=/var/run/postgresql:/var/run/postgresql:rw \
postgres:12.4 \
pg_rewind --target-pgdata=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata --source-server='host=10.0.0.55 port=5432 dbname=postgres user=replicator password=password'
```